# Is any topological subspace of isolated points, of a Banach space, necessarily countable?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, banach-spaces

This question comes up just from curiosity.

Let $B$ a Banach space and $A\subset B$ a topological subspace such that all the points of $A$ are isolated. Then, it is necessarily $A$ countable?

I assume that the answer is yes but I dont know how to do it (I tried build some proofs based in the radius of open balls but I failed). Some proof (or link to a proof) or counterexample will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If $a \in A$ then also $\epsilon a \in A$ for all $\epsilon > 0$...

Comment: @Alqatrkapa yes, fixed. I mean just a subset, a topological subspace, not a vector subspace.

Comment: I think saying just "subset" is clearest then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not.  In $l^\infty$, the set of bounded sequences, with the standard topology, the set of sequences that just contain 0 and 1 is uncountable; and they are isolated.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is studied in more detail [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.08166.pdf).

${}$

${}$

${}$

${}$

(Apologies for self-promotion.)